# How to convert opened CMD to Administrator CMD?

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, administrator

I am trying to open a Command Prompt as administrator, *(elevated)*, from a normal user privileged Command Prompt.

I searched Google a lot, but cannot find a method to achieve it.

Is there any CLI command, to open an `Administrator: Command Prompt`, from a normal `Command Prompt`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the meaning or any other explanation for this command but, it works with all Windows Operating system's (Windows 7,8,8.1,10,11 - Tested). Run this command in your normal user privileged Command Prompt Which will open another `Administrator: CMD` window.

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"
```

I got this Command from Google while searching on the Internet. *If anybody know the meaning of this command plz update (Edit) my Answer!*

Comment: This is intriguing but doesn't open the new DOS window (as I like to call it because Microsoft is so crap) in the same directory. Instead you slide down the snake to stupid old C:\Windows\System32. "System 32". Haha, that's the Microsoft experience all right.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command. Cmd needs to be invoked with the credentials you want to use. So changing users like for example in Terminal on Ubuntu is not possible at the moment. You can open a new Terminal by using

```
runas /user:(UserNameHere) CMD.exe
```

Comment: Can you explain me this elaborately! Plz!

Comment: As written above: You execute the given command in Command Line and replace (UserNameHere) with your administrator username. For example: "runas /user:admin CMD.exe"

Comment: Whenever I try to open by your steps it is asking me for **Enter the password for Admin**

Comment: Then just enter the password for admin and press enter

Comment: Sorry, But I don't know my admin password

Comment: Then you can't execute cmd as admin. Thats the purpose of an authentication. You need the username AND password for an account with the admin rights.

Comment: Again sorry, I really don't know my Admin Account's Password! Is there any other solution for my case?

Comment: you need the password and username for an account which has admin rights. This is not just your "Admin" user. Maybe try it with your own account name. Otherwise you can try to reset your password, but this (including your original question) are things which are super easy to google.