# How to find why Toggle button Crashes?

Tags: java, android-studio, button, android-togglebutton

### How to find why Toggle button Crashes?

---

My Toggle button crashes when changing it's state. My situation: If I change the state of toggle button from *Off* to *On* which Suddenly, crashes the whole app and says "YourApp is not Responding". I don't know what is the error in the code. I am a newbie in Android App Developing. So, I don't know how to find and rectify the errors. If anybody know plz help me in my case. Thanks in Advance!

---

### Here's my Code:

**This is my XML file:**

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn="" />
```

**This is my Java code:**

```
/*------------------------------Screen timeout toggle----------------------------------------------------*/
        ToggleButton toggle_button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);
        toggle_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                try {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                        timeout_on = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Screen Timeout is Disabled (Your screen will doesn't sleep from now!)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        TextView v = (TextView) timeout_on.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                        if( v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        timeout_on.show();
                    } else {
                        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                        timeout_off = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Screen Timeout is Enabled (Your screen will go to sleep as your phone's timeout!)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        TextView v = (TextView) timeout_off.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                        if( v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        timeout_off.show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
/*------------------------------Screen timeout toggle----------------------------------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to your question--*How to find why?* is to see the error stack trace in the **Logcat** window:

[image: screenshot]

You may find some clues from it.

Comment: @SamJoshua Don't worry, I already upvoted. :) (There should be a downvote from someone else. +1 -1 = 0)

Comment: Oh, it's ok! Can you know the answer for this one! https://stackoverflow.com/q/69586161/15590269

Comment: @SamJoshua Sorry, I'm on macOS.

Comment: Anyway, Very thanks for your help!